# What's causing this position change?

Tags: jquery

Thanks to some help from stack overflow, I've managed to get this script working wonderfully:

```
var $count = 4;
var $row = 10;

function across() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow .active .current');
    var $next = $active.next();

    $next.addClass('current');
    $active.animate({ left: '+=100px' }, 800, 'swing').removeClass('current');
    $row += 10;
    $count--;

    if ($count == 0) { 
        $count = 4;
        $row = 10;
        down();
        $($active).stop();
        $('#slideshow .active .bed').animate({ left: '-=100px' }, 1);
        $('.div .bed:first-child').addClass('current');

    }
}
function down() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow .active');
    var $next = $active.next();

    $next.fadeIn("slow").addClass('active');
    $active.fadeOut("slow").removeClass('active');

    if (!$next.length) {
        $("#slideshow .div:first-child").fadeIn("slow").addClass('active');
    }
}
$(function() {
  setInterval(across, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QSfgG/30/

But there is a problem.

On the green parent square, the orange, purple and grey divs slide right across, yet on the other squares, the divs only barely slide onto the left.

It's something to do with the down() function on line 16 of the script. When that's taken out, all of the divs slide on the same amount. However, I can't leave out the down(), as I need it to be called before

```
$('#slideshow .active .bed').animate({ left: '-=100px' }, 1);
$('.div .bed:first-child').addClass('current');
```

on lines 18 and 19. This is so the user doesn't see the divs snapping back to their original position. To clarify, I need the orange, purple and grey divs to slide on the same amount, and I need the parent div to fade out before the user sees the divs snapping back to their original position.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first time (green) the beds are on -20px left so your +=100px moves them 100px to the right, then you change the active div to the next and right after that you move the beds to -=100px and those beds was -20px, you moved them 120px to the left, then the +100 moves them jsut to -20px left

if you put the $('#slideshow .active .bed').animate({ left: '-=100px' }, 1); right above the down() call you can fix it (maybe you want to move also the $($active).stop() call above too)

http://jsfiddle.net/QSfgG/35/

```
if ($count == 0) { 
    $count = 4;
    $row = 10;
    $('#slideshow .active .bed').animate({ left: '-=100px' }, 1);
    down();
    $($active).stop();
    $('.div .bed:first-child').addClass('current');
}
```